# Compare clusters with ground truth

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am facing a problem while comparing the results of my HAC clustering with a ground-truth of manually labeled documents.

The entire dataset is composed of 9k docs, while the ground-truth of 100; the last one allows for multi-label, while the clustering process assigns a document only to one cluster.
Both of them are loaded into a pandas dataframe.

**Clusters**

```
id      label
 0          1
 1          4
 2          9
     ....
9k          3
```

**Ground Truth**

```
id    label1    label2    label3    ...    labeln
 0         0         1         0                1
 1         1         0         1    ...         0
           .....
100        0         0         0    ......      0
```

A '1' in a column means that the document with that ID is assigned to that (or those) label (or labels).

The number of clusters is equal to the number of labels (assigned by the user), let's say --> 14

Now I am doing this:

```
    # computes all possible pairs
    def all_pairs(partition):
        return list(itertools.combinations(partition, 2))

    # main

    indexes = list(map(int, ground_truth['id'].values.tolist()))
    # reduce clusters_file matching only manually analyzed documents:
    reduced_df = clusters.loc[clusters['id'].isin(indexes), :]

    clusters_groups = reduced_df.groupby('label')
    clusters_k = len(clusters_groups)

    for label, df_group in clusters_groups:

        docs_in_cluster = df_group['id'].values.tolist()
        pairs_docs_in_cluster = all_pairs(docs_in_cluster)

        intersection_list = []

        for col in self.ground_truth.columns[1:]:

            # get pairs for this columns/label
            constraints = list(
                map(int, ground_truth.loc[ground_truth[col] == 1, 'id'].values.tolist())
            )
            pairs_constraints = all_pairs(constraints)

            # find sets intersection (of pairs) between current cluster and ground_truth
            intersection = list(set(pairs_constraints) & set(pairs_docs_in_cluster))

            if len(intersection) > 0:
                # concatenate with other labels from ground_truth
                intersection_list += intersection

        ratio = len(intersection_list) / len(pairs_docs_in_cluster) * 100
        print("Cluster: ", label, "[{}] elements".format(df_group.shape[0]),
              'matched {} unique pairs'.format(len(intersection_list)), "--> {:.2f} %".format(ratio))
```

And I am getting something like:

```
Automatic clustering: 8469 elements and k=14 clusters
Ground Truth: 107 elements and m=14 labels
    Cluster:  0 [29] elements matched 111 unique pairs --> 27.34 %
    Cluster:  1 [5] elements matched 1 unique pairs --> 10.00 %
    Cluster:  2 [1] elements matched 0 unique pairs --> 0.00 %
    Cluster:  3 [1] elements matched 0 unique pairs --> 0.00 %
    Cluster:  4 [9] elements matched 5 unique pairs --> 13.89 %
    Cluster:  5 [6] elements matched 2 unique pairs --> 13.33 %
    Cluster:  6 [13] elements matched 27 unique pairs --> 34.62 %
    Cluster:  7 [2] elements matched 0 unique pairs --> 0.00 %
    Cluster:  8 [4] elements matched 3 unique pairs --> 50.00 %
    Cluster:  9 [3] elements matched 0 unique pairs --> 0.00 %
    Cluster:  10 [2] elements matched 0 unique pairs --> 0.00 %
    Cluster:  11 [8] elements matched 2 unique pairs --> 7.14 %
    Cluster:  12 [6] elements matched 10 unique pairs --> 66.67 %
    Cluster:  13 [17] elements matched 29 unique pairs --> 21.32 %
```

That is quite bad, but if I made an inspection of clustering results, they don't look as bad.
Thus I'm thinking that my metric for evaluation (ratio computing) is wrong, but I really can't see where is my mistake (if any).

Comment: Your ground truth has n-columns. Is this because of n humans, which labeled them manually?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [NMI-](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score.html) or the [AMI-score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score.html).

The AMI or (Adjusted Mutual Information) score is rescaled such that random clustering has a score of 0. The NMI (Normalized Mutual Information) is used for cases where you have a different number of clusters and therefore often a golden standard in the clustering community.

Both measures range between 0 and 1, where 0 is considered as random clustering and 1 matches the ground truth perfectly.

There exist also other measures such as F-measure or Purity.

I am not sure, why there exist many different labels in your "ground truth", but probably you can do a majority-voting on these labels to observe one ground truth.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My ground truth has been labeled by my professor, who has stated the topic of each document using is knowledge about the field (real-time systems documents), under the assumption that documents can belong to more than one topic. 
What do you think about analysis with a confusion matrix?

Comment: If you think of an confusion matrix then I would suggest F-measure (or F1-score) because this is a relation between precision and recall.

Comment: But since my GT Is composed by only 100 docs, do I have to consider only those documents from dataset?

Comment: Okay, this was not clear to me. You can cluster the ground truth with the same method you have clustered the other ones. Then you can evaluate how good cluster your method according to this test set. Nevertheless, you need to decide which of the n-columns is the right one.

Comment: I try to explain: I have a corpus, of 9k documents, on which I have performed a clustering session with, let's say Kmeans. After that, I have manually read 100 documents and I have said: "ok, this paper talks about 'real time scheduling', this other talks about 'databases' and 'preemptive scheduling', and so on and so forth...

Ok after that I run all the code above to check how many documents that I have said that have to go together, actually go together in some cluster.